# Group Theory- Zassenhaus Filtration & Other Filtrations

Tags: gr.group-theory

Does someone know of any good papers/books/references of properties of the so-called "Zassenhaus Filtration" of a group $G$ ?

I'm mainly interested in relations between this filtration and closely related ones such as the lower central series (which I actually already found ) , the derived series, etc...

Any good reference will be greatfully acknowledged! I really need to know some properties of this filtration, but can't find any good book/paper that contains such

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a survey and applications of Zassenhaus filtration see [this](http://people.virginia.edu/~mve2x/Research/gssurvey_revised.pdf)  recent survey by Misha Ershov. For a "canonical" text see J. D. Dixon, M. P. F. du Sautoy, A. Mann and D. Segal, Analytic pro-p groups. Second edition. Cambridge Studies in Advanced Mathematics, 61. Cambridge University Press, Cambridge, 1999.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mark Sapir! 

Have you got any idea if one of these references contains some relation between the derived series and the Zass. Filtration? 



Comment: One is inside another by definition (or I do not understand your question). 


Comment: So what you're actually saying is that the derived series is contained in the zassenhaus filtration ? 

What about any results about bounding the other direction ? (something like - the n'th term of the zass. filtration is contained in the 10000n's term of the derived series)? 
Have you got any idea?

Thanks a lot again ! 

Comment: @Jason: Take a cyclic group of order $p^{10000}$. Compare its Z. filtration with the lower central series and the derived series. 